# How to assign one type of object to another type of object value in apex language

Tags: oracle-apex

How to assign one type of object  to another type of object value in apex language

Answer (score 0):

I don't know apex language. Anyway, what you are trying to do sounds like a "casting".
Search for "casting" at the reference manual.